# what happens when the tasklet is interrupted by a hardware interrupt?

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, locking, spinlock, tasklet

I wanted to know this part.
We know that tasklets can't sleep, then if the HW interrupt comes in what happens to the tasklets?

I am facing a crash, in which the tasklet is interrupted by a hW interrupt.
I have used spinlock in my tasklet.

Should I use spinlock_irq_save?

Please, let me know.

Comment: Accept the answer if its clears your doubt

Comment: What are you trying to protect with the 'spinlock'?  Often you can construct things so it doesn't matter.  While `spinlock_irq_save` may be a solution, it will increase the entire system IRQ latency.  Ie, it can be a bad idea depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. Tasklets can be interrupted by HW interrupts, And you should prevent that. By using `spin_lock_irqsave()` and family.

Refer https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/c188.html

If you don't do it and if tasklets are interrupted then you have seen what happens (crash)

Comment: If you do spin_lock_irqsave , you may unknowingly increase interrupt latency. According to tasklet definition, it runs in "interrupt enable" context. Two tasklet of same type can't run concurrently so what is usage of lock ? I see lock only in case of shared resource but i am not able to recall a scenario. Could you please share an example?